# Print the Multivalued data Inside the Hashtable

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

> I am reading 1 million lines of data from the file it contains data of the movies in a given format [FILE DATA IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgpsU.jpg).

**MovieDetails file contains simple get and set functions**

**Problem 1**
I want to print the data of hashmap and it seems like normal method won't work here, I want to print multiple values(movieTitle and Genres) as well.

**Problem 2**
   Basically when I put 1 million records inside the hash table then it put all the keys but every key contains the same value which is the last one (see file data image) and when I am debugging it then it is showing me 3952 (keys and value) but in the output I am getting just 1422 but after overriding my class toString() it is showing me 1539 (keys and value).[NEW OUTPUT AFTER OVERRIDING](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GHSN.jpg) 
please check out the output image [OUTPUT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK2Cc.jpg)

[MoviesTable DEBUG data Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfETA.jpg)

**PLEASE EXPLAIN TO ME WHY I AM GETTING THESE ERRORS AND HOW CAN I CORRECT IT**
Thank you

```
 MovieDetails mb = new MovieDetails();
        Hashtable<Integer, MovieDetails> moviesTable=new Hashtable<Integer, MovieDetails>();
        try {

            String contentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/hp/Desktop/movies.dat"));

            while ((contentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                mb.setMovieID(Integer.valueOf(contentLine.split("::")[0]));
                mb.setTitle(contentLine.split("::")[1]);
                mb.setGenres(contentLine.split("::")[2]);
                moviesTable.put(mb.getMovieID(), mb);
            }

            for (Entry<Integer, MovieBean> entry : moviesTable.entrySet()) {
                Integer key = entry.getKey();
                MovieBean value = entry.getValue();

                System.out.println ("Key: " + key + " Value: " + value);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null)br.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


**OUTPUT IMAGE**
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZi4e.jpg
```

Comment: The MovieDetails class needs an override of the toString() method. Right now it's using the default.  Make it output what you want.

Comment: Cool, After overriding it toString() i am getting my data by my second problem is still there help me with that as well ( i have updated it with image)

Comment: I need to see your MovieDetails class.  Especially the toString() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your MovieDetails toString method should look something like:

```
public String toString() {
       return( "" + getTitle() + " " + getGenres() );
}
```

Also move :

```
MovieDetails mb = new MovieDetails();
```

to

```
 while ((contentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
      MovieDetails mb = new MovieDetails();
  (then rest of loop)
```

Comment: well it cover almost 75% of my problem and last problem remains that is I am still getting 1522 (keys and values) as compared to 3952. Any idea for that

Comment: @SamarthSaxena I have not seen your code. I made an educated guess on your problems, but without seeing the code I can't answer. If you need more help, please post the code.